# Slide not working

Tags: jquery, plugins, slider, slide

I know i'm a bit newbie in coding, especially in jquery but i just can't seem to figure out why i can't get a slide plugin to work on my website... I've already tried more than one plugin but they all seem to fail...

Here's my code:

Calling Jquery and Slippry Plugin-

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery('selector').slippry()
});
</script>
```

HTML -

```
<ul id="slippry-demo">
  <li>
  <a href="#slide1"><img src="images/22.png" alt="Welcome to Slippry!"></a>
  </li>
  <li>
  <a href="#slide2"><img src="images/11.png" alt="cenas nices!"></a>
  </li>
  <li>
  <a href="#slide3"><img src="images/33.png" alt="such responsivness, much slide, wow!"></a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

And for the CSS, i just linked the css file that came with the plugin.

In my website, the result is just 3 images showing at the same time one on top of the other...

What can i do?
Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to include library file for Slippry Plugin to get called.. after jQuery library is included.

Comment: I've already included but still nothing...

Answer (score 0):

The name of your slippry element in the HTML - the 'selector' for slippry - is '#slippry-demo'. So in your javascript, try this:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery('#slippry-demo').slippry()
});
</script>
```